# Using CRT electron gun

Tags: energy, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation

I am a high-school student working with CRT electron gun. I want to make a setup using a CRT gun of an old television set where the beam will hit a target metal. I am making this setup at my home. I want to ask if will it be harmful or if will it cause any damage to lifestyle or emit harmful radiation.

Comment: If it was safe to use in an old TV set, then it will be safe to use now. Remember that it needs to run in vacuum.

Comment: High voltage from the power supply is likely to be the biggest danger. Electron guns accelerate electrons to high energy. In some color televisions, they emitted Xrays when they hit the screen. The screens had thick glass to absorb them.

Comment: @mmesser314 - thick, leaded glass...